# CSS/HTML: What is producing this sub-menu arrow?

Tags: css

Can you see what is causing this up arrow @ [this page](http://test.doig.com.au/vm-home.html).

[image]

I have right-clicked on it > inspect element, and I am shown:

```
.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu
```

but I see no CSS rules to generate the up arrow there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pseudo-element `:after` declared with the following rule:
`.genesis-nav-menu li:last-of-type .sub-menu li:first-child a:after`

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I found it really hard to keep that :after seudo element visible in the code inspector. Most the time it was invisible, which is probably why I couldn't find it.

Comment: **Pro Tip:** if you place your dev tool pop-up in the right location (like I had in the screenshot) you can move from the sub-menu dropdown directly to the pop-up without having the dropdown menu disappear again. Once you're over your dev tool pop-up you can drag it out the way and inspect elements at leisure - and so long as you don't hover back over the page in question (or off your dev tool pop-up if it's still on the same monitor) the dropdown sub-menu should remain displayed as though you where still hovering over it. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The following css code is creating this issue:
.genesis-nav-menu li:last-of-type .sub-menu li:first-child a::after 
{left: 90%; }

when this code is removed there is no arrow that is showing right now.

Comment: I marked the other response as the answer because he showed me where in the style sheet the corresponding CSS rules were Gurpreet.